# Selecionar registros sob multiplas condições

Tags: mysql

Ajuda no código para selecionar no MySQL. As condições são:

1. para registros de mesma 'net' e 'hora', seleciona-se o primeiro registro (id mín) e outro registro se o 'AP' for diferente
2. para registros de mesma 'hora' e 'net' diferentes, adota-se a condição acima para cada grupo de mesma 'net'

**Exemplo**

> para hora 00:13:56 selecionar registros 38 e 40 (net= 11)
>   para hora 00:13:56 selecionar registros 42 e 43 (net= 80)
>   para hora 07:30:21 selecionar registros 46 e 48 (net= 11)
>   para hora 07:30:21 selecionar registro 50 (net= 30)

**Dados da Tabela**

```
id  net   hora     AP
38  11  00:13:56    4
39  11  00:13:56    4
40  11  00:13:56    1
41  11  00:13:56    4
42  80  00:13:56    5
43  80  00:13:56    2
44  80  00:13:56    5
45  80  00:13:56    5
46  11  07:30:21    4
47  11  07:30:21    4
48  11  07:30:21    3
49  11  07:30:21    4
50  30  07:30:21    1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize o `GROUP BY` para agrupar os registros pelos campos `net`, `hora` e `AP`:

```
SELECT MIN(id) FROM tabela GROUP BY net, hora, AP
```

Comment: Roberto, muito obrigado! Ainda estou aprendendo a usar o MySQL, não sabia que o group by poderia ser utilizado para agrupar vários registros de uma vez. Sua dica resolveu meu problema!